Angular testing: correct way to detectChanges when mocking a service that is used on ngOnInit
When I uncomment the first call to fixture.detectChanges(), the test does not work as expected.
The IA told me to:

Set up the mock before creating the component: This ensures that the component is created with the mocked service in place.
Trigger change detection after setting up the mock: This forces the component to re-render based on the updated mock data.

My questions are:

Why is that?
Is there a way to force the change detection, regardless of input change?
What if I want to call detectChanges() on beforeEach()? Then I can't setup mocks inside specific tests?
Is it a good practice to call createComponent inside each specific test (it) instead?

OBS: I am using Angular 11.
test code:
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { MyComponent } from './my.component';
import { SomeService } from '../services/some.service';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let compiled;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('SomeService', ['aMethod']);

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: SomeService, useValue: spy }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  it('should show another mock', () => {
    // This code was moved from beforeEach()
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    compiled = fixture.nativeElement;

    // *** MOCK VALUE ISN'T PICKED IF THIS IS UNCOMMENTED ***
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const mock: jasmine.SpyObj<SomeService> = TestBed.inject(SomeService) as jasmine.SpyObj<SomeService>;;
    mock.aMethod.and.returnValue('MOCKED VALUE');

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(compiled.querySelector('p').innerHTML).toContain('MOCKED VALUE');
  });
});

component code:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeService } from '../services/some.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  template: `
    <p>
      myPropIs = {{ propThatReadsFromService }}
    </p>
  `,
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  propThatReadsFromService: string = 'not set yet';
  constructor(private someService: SomeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.propThatReadsFromService = this.someService.aMethod() || 'did not pick value from service';
  }
}


Initialize the component on the beforeEach, since other test cases, can just use the component, this gets rid of code duplication.
Then setup the spy, after which you can recreate the component, this guarantees the component is initialized with the spy.
Where detectChanges is required for angular change detection to run and the value to reflect in the HTML.
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { MyComponent } from './my.component';
import { SomeService } from '../services/some.service';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let compiled;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('SomeService', ['aMethod']);

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: SomeService, useValue: spy }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    compiled = fixture.nativeElement;
  });

  it('should show another mock', () => {
    const mock: jasmine.SpyObj<SomeService> = TestBed.inject(SomeService) as jasmine.SpyObj<SomeService>;;
    mock.aMethod.and.returnValue('MOCKED VALUE');
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    compiled = fixture.nativeElement;

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(compiled.querySelector('p').innerHTML).toContain('MOCKED VALUE');
  });
});


I think the answers you are looking for have to do with order of operations.
Why is that?
I view it this way

TestBed.CreateComponent calls the constructor of your component
The very first time fixture.detectChanges is called is when your onInit method fires

If your constructor (or the variables defined at component level) rely on values from your dependencies, your mocks will need to have those values prepared already for them to get assigned during construction.
For test setup ease, I tend to put all of my dependency assignments in the onInit method of my component. This allows me to grab the mock inside of my it and setup any changed data, then call fixture.detectChanges to have the component use those values.
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let compiled;
  // I usually declare my mocks here so that I can assign right after the configureTestingModule call

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('SomeService', ['aMethod']);

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: SomeService, useValue: spy }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    compiled = fixture.nativeElement;
  });

  it('should show another mock', () => {
    // I do all of these assignments at the end of the beforeEach
    // but I also declare the variables inside of the describe
    const mock: jasmine.SpyObj<SomeService> = TestBed.inject(SomeService) as jasmine.SpyObj<SomeService>;;
    mock.aMethod.and.returnValue('MOCKED VALUE');
   
   // I would either do this here or in the beforeEach, but not both
   // Each time you createComponent it can take a little bit of time
   // IF you decide to do this in each test, suggest creating a function
   // as there can get to be a list of items to assign
   // fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
   // compiled = fixture.nativeElement;

    fixture.detectChanges(); // first detectChanges will call onInit

    expect(compiled.querySelector('p').innerHTML).toContain('MOCKED VALUE');
  });
});

Is there a way to force the change detection, regardless of input change?
Why yes, however I tend to avoid this as I like to control when change detection runs. Plus, having to include a call to await whenStable can wait through your timers/debounce for the actual amount of time instead of moving through fake time.
What if I want to call detectChanges() on beforeEach()? Then I can't setup mocks inside specific tests?
I mean, yes. This would limit what you can change before the constructor and the onInit.
There is a place and time for an inner describe with its own beforeEach for when your user is going to take different actions, but the data setup is the same.
Is it a good practice to call createComponent inside each specific test (it) instead?
If a lot of assignments happen at constructor time and you need to control the values, then yes. This has to do with how you write the component. When this is necessary I will create a function that does all of the TestBed.createComponent and dependency assignments for me. I honestly use functions in my test code a lot to help with readability, as they can get very messy and then hard to maintain.
